# How to map a windows service program's file

Tags: c#, service

I am working on a windows service c# program.

I need to use a file. Here is my code

```
const string mail_file_path = @"template\mailbody.html";
```

But according to my log, there is an error like this:

> Error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\template\mailbody.html'.

I use the app.configuration to use another file

```
<add key="TimeStampFilePath" value="timestamp.ini" />
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeStampFilePath"]);
```

But I can't read the file.

When I run this project as a simple windows console project, it works. But after I run it using windows service mode, the two problems appear.

Comment: Where is the file exactly? Please provide the full path.

Comment: VS2010\Projects\ProjectName\bin\Debug\template\mailbody.html
VS2010\Projects\ProjectName\bin\Debug\timestamp.init

Comment: @QuianLi : My answer should work if you copy template folder where the server exe is.

Comment: Is that where you expect it to be when you deploy the service?

Comment: @Oded: Is there any way to update the windows service setup project to deploy the "templates(along with files)" folder into window service installed directory while doing installation. Means is we need to do any setting in setup & deploy project to copy those templates folder while creating setup installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
// dir is path where your service EXE is running
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);    
// mail_file_path is where you need to search
string mail_file_path = Path.Combine(dir , @"\template\mailbody.html");
```

Take my answer as an integration to @CharithJ's post, which is definitely correct!!

Comment: Sorry, it still not work. Where should I put the template folder?

Comment: @QianLi: take dir where you service EXE is running and create _template_ subdir there. Take a look to my edited post.

Comment: I've put the template folder into the service EXE running foder and change the value of mail_file_path like you suggested. But still, it doesn't work, now the error become Error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\template\mailbody.html' instead of the old one Error: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\system32\template\mailbody.html'.

Comment: @QianLi: where does the EXE reside? Write to a log file the value of _dir_ string after executing exe and see what's happening: the real EXE dir and _dir_ value should be the same...

Answer (score 0):

If you have got template\mailbody.html in the same directory where the service exe resides. Try something like below and see. You could find the folder where the windows service .exe resides.

```
string mail_file_path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + 
                        "\template\mailbody.html";
```

Or this also can help [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the problem, thanks to the suggestion from @Macro. I get the windows service mapping directory using REGISTER API, then setting the working directory the same with it. Then I can use the relative path to get the file I need.